# Trouble Understanding Python Scope

Tags: python

I have trouble understanding Python Scope. If you can help, I'll be thankful.
This is my code:

```
def msgCmd(x):
    if x[0] == '/':
        cmd = x[1:len(x)]
        print(cmd)

def Cmd(x):
    if x == "hello":
        print("Hi how can I help you?")
    elif x == "music":
        print("Let's rock!")

while 1:
    inp = input()
    cmd = ''
    msgCmd(inp)
    Cmd(cmd)
```

I am essentially trying to type in a command using /command and get two results. One being only the command name following slash and the other being a result of what it did. Say, I enter /music. I am expecting 'music' as the first result and 'Let's rock!' as the next. But, somehow I am failing to retrieve the second desired result, possibly due to a Python Scope problem.

Also, please explain why this code works as it should when I add global cmd at the top of the function msgCmd(x) like this:

```
def msgCmd(x):
    global cmd
    if x[0] == '/':
        cmd = x[1:len(x)]
        print(cmd)
```

And, why doesn't it run as desired when global cmd added here outside function:

```
global cmd

def msgCmd(x):
    if x[0] == '/':
        cmd = x[1:len(x)]
        print(cmd)
```

or here within the while loop:

```
while 1:
    inp = input()
    cmd = ''
    msgCmd(inp)
    global cmd
    Cmd(cmd)
```

Comment: note that the usage of `global` isn't recommended due to a few caveats: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil

Answer (score 1):

return the value of `msgCmd` first:

```py
def msgCmd(x):
    if x[0] == '/':
        cmd = x[1:len(x)]

    return cmd # right here
```

then get the value of that function so you can pass that value to another function:

```py
    ...
    cmd_str = msgCmd(inp)
    Cmd(cmd_str)
```

Comment: It proved to be helpful. Thank you.